# Flatten LINQ subselect so 1..n becomes one row

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Order with a list of Stations linked to a Station setup:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ..
    ..
    public List<OrderStation> OrderStations { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    ..
    ..
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Station Station { get; set; }
}  

public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    ..
    ..
}
```

Order->OrderStations<-Station

There can be any number of OrderStations to an Order (same number of OrderStations for all Orders). The OrderStations should be ordered by the DisplayOrder of the Station.

What I try to get back is:

```
o.Name, os[0].Status, os[..].Status, os[16].Status
```

where OrderStation is sorted by OrderStation.Station.DisplayOrder

I'm not that used to LINQ and totally stucked trying to flatten the sub-select out like this!

Comment: You should show a sample with a single order(the C# code that initializes it) and a desired result.

Comment: in order to have *a collection of a collection* flatten, you can try using `SelectMany`

Comment: There can be more stations added over time...

Comment: It would help if you provide the expected function prototype

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable.OrderBy`. If the collection "can be any number of `OrderStations`" you should not use fixed properties in the anonymous type for every `Status`. Instead use a property that is an ordered collection:

```
var q = new
{
    order.Name,
    OrderedStatuses = order.OrderStations
        .OrderBy(os => os.Station.DisplayOrder)
        .ToList()
};
```